# Business objects: Aggregating calculated measure on level of month_week

Tags: aggregate, business-objects, measure

Situation:
in table, I use a calculated measure whose calculation base is on daily level; works well so far
now I want to aggregate it on month_week level (=FormatDate([Datum];"MM-W"))
with all known to me context operators or other approaches, I cannot do it; there result always either unaggregated sums or sums whose aggregation is not correct

Comment: In the objects returned, what is the data type of  [Datum]?  I assume date... but want to check first.

Comment: yes, it is of type "date"

Comment: I'd need a MCVE (Minimally Complete,  Verifiable Example) of "what's not correct" because I'm not able to recreate the unaggregated sums, or sum's whose aggregation is not correct.  Do you have a sample dataset which is presenting an error?  maybe lay it out in a CSV fashion in your question or using  https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to help you generate a well formed ascii table.

Answer (score 0):

While not an answer, I'm trying to clairify the question and doing so with graphics helps...

I'm not able to recreate your issue.  I'm using formula ="FormatDate([DateField];"MM-W") in a local variable and then using that variable and measure in the report.  Example below.  Can you provide a dataset which is causing the problem?

1. Is it at the edges meaning week 0 or week 4/5? or month 1 or 12?
2. Is it that your data has "Bad dates" (either missing or invalid) so the format date function isn't working?

Here's a small example I created using excel data source of dummy data; all of which sum perfectly to my totals listed by day, and by MM-W format.

[image]

Comment: Based on your demonstration that proved to me that the aggregation on week level must basically work, I rewied all the elements that matter in the (quite complicated) calculation of the measure to aggregate.
And then: Behind the background that the measure is calculated on a day level (by using min and max hour/minute of item processing, I have seen that the intended forcing to calculate on a day level could made work by using the "forall" context operator (rather than with the "in" operator. Afterwards, the desired aggregation worked well!
many thanks!

Comment: Excellent!  Be sure to ask the [Duck](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/); he's pretty smart; and by proxy, you are!